# How do I make a batch file recognize file extensions in For loop?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm trying to make a batch file, a newer one than the one I made last time, and  I'm
planning to add to my previous program, for organize all of the respective images it
finds into folders corresponding to their extensions.

So, say it finds a `.jpg` file, it generates a folder called "`jpg`" and copies the file into it.

I've got something that sorta works, but it depends too much on chance if the file name doesn't have a period in it already.

How could I make my batch file recognize a file's extension?

```
@echo off

set existing=0
for /r %%a in (*.bmp,*.gif,*.ico,*.jpeg,*.jpg,*.kra,*.png,*.svg,*.tif,*.tiff,*.webp) do echo %%a>>boobatest.txt

pause
cls

rem for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=." %%b in (%cd%\boobatest.txt) do echo %%b, %%c>>boobatestpt2.txt

for /f "tokens=1-2delims=." %%b in (%cd%\boobatest.txt) do (
    set "extension=%%c"
    call :vibecheck
    copy "%%b.%%c" "%cd%\boobatest\%%c"
   ) >nul

pause
del boobatest.txt

:vibecheck
if %existing%==1 exit /b 0

mkdir "%cd%\boobatest\%extension%"

set existing=1
exit /b 0
```

I also fully understand this is probably not even close to the smallest
possible way to write the code of this program, but I'm not the most
experienced when it comes to batch in this sense.

I'm not sure how I would make this code shorter yet keep its current design.

Comment: an extension is just part of the name (its only a convention, and assists in finding default programs). are you indicating that you have filenames without an extension on them? Are you sure they aren't there (is windows configured to show file type extensions in Explorer)? if the filename doesn't have an extension on it, I think you need to find out what kind of content it has, but that will require some other tooling that can analyze the contents and determine what its internal format is.

Comment: I think they're saying the opposite, that they have filenames with multiple dots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use tokens with a dot delimiter if you don't know how many dots there might be. Cmd has a built-in FOR variable modifier `~x` - if `%%A` in a batch script (or `%A` in a command line) is a filename then `%%~nA` is the name and `%%~xA` is the extension, which is what you see if you read backwards from the end of the whole filename + extension string, and stop at the first dot.

You can read about all of the tilde (~) variable modifiers by typing `FOR /?` at the prompt or here [SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) (they also work with parameters %0, %1, %2, etc)

```
E:\test\extensions>dir
 Volume in drive E is SATA3-01
 Volume Serial Number is 452C-48AE

 Directory of E:\test\extensions

14/05/2021  20:34    <DIR>          .
14/05/2021  20:34    <DIR>          ..
14/05/2021  20:27                 8 hello.txt
14/05/2021  20:28                 8 hello.txt.xyz
14/05/2021  20:29                 8 hello.txt.xyz.pqr
14/05/2021  20:34                 8 hello.txt.xyz.pqr.chicken.burger
               4 File(s)             32 bytes
               2 Dir(s)    743675928576 bytes free

E:\test\extensions>for %A in (*.*) do @echo %A extension is %~xA
hello.txt extension is .txt
hello.txt.xyz extension is .xyz
hello.txt.xyz.pqr extension is .pqr
hello.txt.xyz.pqr.chicken.burger extension is .burger
```

Answer (score 0):

```bath
@echo off

setlocal && cd /d "%~dp0"
set "_ext=bmp,gif,ico,jpeg,jpg,kra,png,svg,tif,tiff,webp"

for /f usebackq^tokens^=* %%i in (`^<con: %__AppDir__%where.exe /r . *.%_ext:,=,*.%
`)do 2>nul mkdir "%cd%\boobatest\%%~xi" & 2>nul copy "%%~fi" "%cd%\boobatest\%%~xi"

endlocal & goto :eof
```

---

- You can replace your command `For /R` + `For /F` + `call :Lable` without need to create, read, `delete` any file, using one just one `For /f` with recursive `where` command...

```bath
for /f usebackq^tokens^=* %%i in (`^<con: %__AppDir__%where.exe /r . *.eXtension,*.eXtension,*.eXtension,*.eXtension..)do...
```

- You are calling a `:label` without passing the arguments **`%existing%`** and **`%extension%`**, will resulting in the variables having no defined value within the function... also, to compare **`if "%strings%"=="sTrInGs"`** is some diferent to compare numbers, ***`if %integer% equ 1`***

```bath
call :vibecheck %existing% %extension%

:vibecheck 
rem :: Argument 1º <==> %~1 <==> %existing%
rem :: Argument 2º <==> %~2 <==> %extension%

if %existing% == 1 <==> if %~1 equ 1 exit /b 0

mkdir "%cd%\boobatest\%extension%" mkdir "%cd%\boobatest\%~2"
set existing=1
exit /b 0
```

---

- You can set one varible to use with your loop...

```bath
set "_ext=bmp,gif,ico,jpeg,jpg,kra,png,svg,tif,tiff,webp"

:: in loop concatenate ::       variable         with manipulation :: 
::                      *.  +   %_ext:,=,*.%     <==>    , <==> ,*.
::                      *.  +   bmp,*.gif,*.ico,*.jpeg,*.jpg,*.kra,*.png,*.svg,*.tif,*.tiff,*.webp

:: results :: 
::           *.bmp,*.gif,*.ico,*.jpeg,*.jpg,*.kra,*.png,*.svg,*.tif,*.tiff,*.webp

your for loop command is.. 
for /f usebackq^tokens^=* %%i in (`^<con: %__AppDir__%where.exe /r .. *.bmp,*.gif,*.ico,*.jpeg,*.jpg,*.kra,*.png,*.svg,*.tif,*.tiff,*.webp`)do ...
```

- You can use a loop to create the destination folder using `mkdir \Targe\extension_folder`, and in adding `2>nul`, the folder will be created when it does not exist, but if it exists, only an error message is displayed, where, redirecting to `nul`, no interference results from an error without major achievements.

```bath
...)do 2>nul mkdir "%cd%\boobatest\%%~xi" & 2>nul copy "%%~fi" "%cd%\boobatest\%%~xi"
```

**Obs.: 1.** I'm not answer your question, so, consider the **@[Michael Harvey](https://superuser.com/users/78120/michael-harvey)** answer...

**Obs.: 2.** Getting the eXtension (**`%~xi`**) is the least of the problems in your code (and has already been answered by  **@[Michael Harvey](https://superuser.com/users/78120/michael-harvey)**), the functioning of it depends on other considerations/corrections you need in the code.

---

***// Edit...**

```bath
@echo off

setlocal && cd/d "%~dp0"
set "_skip="%cd%\boobatest"
set "_ext=bmp,gif,ico,jpeg,jpg,kra,png,svg,tif,tiff,webp"

for /f usebackq^tokens^=* %%i in (`^<con: ^<nul ^ 
;%__AppDir__%where.exe /r . *.%_ext:,=,*.% ^| %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /vi "%_skip%"`
)do >nul 2>&1 (mkdir "%cd%\boobatest\%%~xi" & copy/y "%%~fi" "%cd%\boobatest\%%~xi")

endlocal & goto :eof
```

- Another thing to consider, would be if you are going to run again, and or, if the destination folder already contains any file of those extensions, then you would have to skip that folder in your loop, also inform the action of overwriting existing files to copy.

**Edit...//***

---

#### Additional Resources:

- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /F`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for)
- [`Copy /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html)
- [`Where /?`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/where)
- [`FindSTR /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [`Goto :Lable` | `Call :Label`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)
- Undocumented variables :

  - [`%__AppDir__%`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6137)  | [`%__CD__%`](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6137)
  - [Environment](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)
- [How-to: Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes at the Windows command line](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)
- [DOS Tips - String Manipulation in Batch files: `%var:|StringToFind|=|StringToReplace|%`](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)